# my jquery plugin & setInterval - animation only runs 1 frame

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-plugins, setinterval

I need to animate a sprite on hover and thats it! I tried some plugins but decided to write my own. Here it is:

```
 (function($) {
    function animate(opts, t) {
        if (opts.bgpos === opts.width * opts.frames) {
            t.css('background-position-x', '0px');
        } else {
            opts.bgpos = opts.bgpos + opts.width;
            t.css('background-position-x', opts.bgpos + 'px');
        }
    }
    $.fn.spin = function(options) {
        var t = $(this);
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.spin.defaults, options);
        var frames = t.data('frames');
        var bgpos = parseInt(t.css('background-position-x'),10);
        opts = $.extend({
            'frames': frames,
            'bgpos': bgpos
        }, opts);
        setInterval(animate(opts, t), 1000 / opts.fps);
    };
    $.fn.spin.defaults = {
        fps: 7,
        width: 236
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[It's called spin because the sprite animation is of a spin]

I'm calling it like this:

```
$('article.post').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var t = $(this);
        t.children('div.filmstrip').spin();
    }
});
```

However the animation only moves one frame per hover. From what I've found this is because I am using function call not reference in my setInterval. I can make the setInterval loop if I remove the () however my animate function fails without its variables.

How do I get my $(this) & options into my animate function with setInterval? Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) requires a parameter of type `function`, but you supply the return value of `animate`, which is `undefined`.

When you write

```
setInterval(animate(opts, t), 1000 / opts.fps);
```

you are telling the JS engine to execute `animate(opts, t)` immediately, and then call `setInterval` on the returned value, which in this case is `undefined`, since your function doesn't explicitely returns anything. So is like the following happened:

```
var animated = animate(opts, t); //animated == undefined
setInterval(animated, 1000/opts.fps);
```

Thus you are not scheduling anything. You may want to use a function literal

```
setInterval(function() {animate(opts, t);}, 1000 / opts.fps);
```

so that the closure

```
function() {
  animate(opts, t);
}
```

is passed to `setInterval` and is scheduled for later execution.

Answer (score 1):

you're passing the *result* of your `animate` method to `setInterval` - im guessing you want to actually call that function each time.

Just wrap your function call in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function(){ animate(opts, t) }, 1000 / opts.fps);
```